# What is with the random } at the bottom of the sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

There seems to be a bug at the bottom of stack exchange sites. A random "}". First noticed it on the Drupal site but it appears on the Stack Overflow site too.

In fact, scroll down to the bottom of this page and observe.

Answer (score 13):

Yup, an extra closing brace slipped into a master view at some point...it'll be corrected next build.

*Update:* invalid HTML isn't something we want to be throwing out all day, build completed.

Comment: @Sam152: Obligatory xkcd link: http://xkcd.com/859/